# Notation for bijection

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to specify an explicit bijection between small, finite sets.

For example, to specify a specific $f \colon \{ a,b,c \} \to \{ x,y,z \}$, I could define $f$ by

$$
f(a)=y \\
f(b)=x \\
f(c)=z
$$

Is there some easily-recognizable notation for this, that is shorter than what I have written?

For example, I could write $f= \{ (a,y), (b,x), (c,z) \}$ or say that $f$ is given by $a \leftrightarrow y, b \leftrightarrow x$ and $c \leftrightarrow z$. Are there other (better) options?

Comment: Maybe $f: (a,b,c) \mapsto (y,x,z)$ is more compact.

Comment: @JackR Some may confuse this with an ordered triple.

Comment: They might, but the context should make it pretty clear I think.

Comment: $f:\{a,b,c\}\hookrightarrow\{x,y,z\}$. It is enough to say it is injective.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: This allows me to specify that the mapping is injective, but not what it is.

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}\hookrightarrow\{x_a,x_b,x_c\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a universally accepted notation for this. Any of the three options you mentioned should be fine. Though, for the third one, it might be better to replace "$\leftrightarrow$" with "$\mapsto$".

Comment: Any reason why $\mapsto$ is better? Just because it is more standard?

Comment: @Peter Because $\mapsto$ is usually reserved for  saying that the *element* on the left maps to the *element* on the right. Generally $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are used when you are indicating domain and codomain like $f:\{a, b, c \} \to \{x, y, z \}$.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to view such bijections as permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$. And for those we have compact notations like cycle decomposition. Formally, let $X=\{x,y,z\}$ and $A=\{a,b,c\}$. Fix some bijections $\chi\colon \{1,2,3\}\to X$ and $\alpha\colon\{1,2,3\}\to A$. Then any bijection $X\to A$ is uniquely determined by some permutation $\sigma\in S_3$. That is, given $\sigma\in S_3$ we get a bijection $\alpha\circ\sigma\circ\chi^{-1}\colon X\to A$ and any bijection can be produced in such a way. Now take your favourite notation for peremutations.

Comment: This is a really interesting approach, but it's not quite clear to me what σ is actually doing here.  Would it be possible to see an example of your approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your function as
$$
f= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
y & x & z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If the domain is fixed (which is common), then the second line determines the function; thus, you may also simply write $
f=(y~x~z)$.

Since $z$ is fixed, you can also write $f=(y~x)$ with the convention that any element that does not appear is mapped to itself.